# Install Shutter on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, repository

I'm trying to figure out a way to install shutter on Centos. Are there any repos somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

From [`shutter-project.org`'s download page<sup>(1)</sup>](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/third-party-packages/):

> **Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and Derivatives like CentOS, Scientific Linux etc.)**
>
> One of our users (Nux) provides a small repository for RHEL 6. The repository is designed to coexist with Fedora’s EPEL repository.
>   In order to add those repos to your system and install Shutter you can use the following commands:
>
> ```
> rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
> rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el6.nux.noarch.rpm 
> yum install shutter
> ```

This could work.

*(1)* the first result Google presents for *"shutter centos"*.